# Can you have a charge of 0 C?

Tags: charge, terminology

My textbook says that there are only two types of charges: positive and negative. Then would it be correct to say that the neutron (for instance) has charge $0\ \rm C$?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question (v2) because it seems to be more about semantics than physics.

Comment: Voting to reopen since the reason given for closing is silly. Questions about the usage and meaning of terms in *physics* are entirely legitimate here. Yes, they are questions about semantics, but as long as they are questions about semantics in *physics* that is not a good reason to close a question.

Comment: I don't know why this question has been downvoted. If the answer is obvious, what is it?

Comment: My hunch is that the charge of a neutron is undefined as the neutron is not charged. That is, you cannot have $q=0\ \rm C$.

Comment: @Ghoster It's consistent with the statement that there are only two kinds of charges: positive and negative. I think we should change our terminology and say that there are _three_ kinds of charge: positive, negative, and neutral.

Comment: @gandalf61 :  Questions about semantics are fine if they illuminate some underlying physics.  "Should I call a photon a particle?" might be fine, for example, if it elicits answers describing the **physical** reasons why this might or might not be a good choice of terminology.  But for a  question like this, which comes down to whether it's better to say "no charge" or "zero charge", there is obviously nothing interesting at stake.  Should economics.stackexchange allow a question about whether it's better to say that a free good has "zero price" or "no price"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics.

Comment: A neutrino would have been your best choice to show that zero charge particles exist since they are the zero charge elementary particles of the standard model.

Comment: A subatomic particle manifests itself as an electric charge when it has an electric field.  No field measurable, no charge. Of course, you can call a neutron a neutral charge, but what you are saying is that it has no electric field.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a physics question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say that an object has a velocity of $0$ m/s or you can say that it is stationary. You can say that an object has a mass of $0$ kg or you can say that it is massless. Similarly, you can say that an object has a charge of $0$ coulombs or that it has no charge - either choice is correct.

Comment: But a massless object does not exist.

Comment: I think we should change our terminology and say that there are _three_ kinds of charge: positive, negative, and neutral. That seems to me the best way forward.

Comment: 1) Massless particles do exist. Eg photons.  2) charge exists as any integer multiple of the quark charge, which includes positive, zero and negative numbers.  It's better to say there is really only one kind of charge (in electromagnetic theory) and it can be any integer multiple of a tiny finite charge

Comment: @Thomas I have given you the answer according to standard usage in mainstream physics. You now appear to be promoting your own individual terminology for electric charge. This is not the right place to do that.

Comment: @gandalf61 I apologize.